# CKeditor instance not created when loading content loaded using ajax

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using `JQuery inline CKeditor` with multiple div elements and onchange plugin to save data through ajax on change. When using static div elements all works fine. But I want to change div elements on button click for which I am using ajax which returns html. When loaded dynamic div elements `CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {});` is not working. Whats going wrong in this procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this method in one of my project. So, you call a ckeditor function after your content is added into DOM. Similar to this:

```
function ckeditor(elem) {
  try {
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(elem.get(0), {
        toolbar: [{
            name: 'basicstyles',
            items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'TextColor', 'BGColor']
        }],
    });
   } catch (err) {
    //catch error if any
   }
}
```

Here `elem` will be the jquery selector element on which you want the ckeditor.

Another method which I suggest is:

```
$(document).on('focus','your-selector',function(){
 var elem = $(this);
//Your ckeditor code goes here.
});
```

I didn't tried this method but you can give it a try.

Comment: If you set `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;` once, that's enough. There's no need to put it before every `CKEDITOR.inline` call.

Answer (score 0):

Everything's alright with [`instanceCreated`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceCreated) event. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/ewKd2/).

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="newEditor()">Create new editor</button>
```

JS

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( evt ) {
    console.log( 'instanceCreated', evt, evt.editor );
} );

function newEditor() {
    // This HTML could've come from AJAX data.
    var el = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<div contenteditable="true">Hello world</div>' );
    CKEDITOR.document.getBody().append( el );

    // Create editor instance on the new element.
    CKEDITOR.inline( el, {
        toolbarGroups: [
            { name: 'basicstyles' }
        ]
    } );
}
```